# Python: encode text from querystring

Tags: python, urllib

I have url and querystring

```
yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%2F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%2010%20%D0%BC%D0%BB.&lr=11168
%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%2F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%2010%20%D0%BC%D0%BB.

yandex.ru/search/?text=02-250%20%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%2010%20%D0%BC%D0%BB.%20alessandro&lr=11168
02-250%20%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%2010%20%D0%BC%D0%BB.%20alessandro
```

I tried to get query with `urllib.parse.parse_qs` 
but it returns an error `ValueError`.

Is there any way to get querystring from url?

Comment: Can you show the exact code that's generating the error (and the full traceback)? Running `parse_qs()` on that works fine for me.

Comment: use import `urllib;urllib.unquote('string')`